# I wana know how to use an sms API in php

Tags: php, infobip, infobip-api

Hi i'm trying to create an application to send notification SMSs to people, i wana select their name and phone number from the database and send them smss using the following API:

http://api.infobip.com/api/v3/sendsms/plain?user=test&password=test&sender=Friend&SMSText=messagetext&SendDateTime=1d2h5m3s&GSM=38598514674

I am new in php programming

the following is the code i used to select from the database

Comment: You say there is code... There is no code `:/`

Comment: If you're new to the programming world, welcome. Integrating sms into a web application is a nice touch, twilio has an easy to use api which sends messages,they offer a free trial which requires a mobile to be authorized, which is great for testing. Though, If you're new. I'd suggest reading the basics and understanding them before moving to more complex integrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common API's they will provide a PHP file and a certificate file ( optional) and we can use those files to drirectly send SMS.

A rough code looks like follows

```
$sms=new SMSApi();
$sms->senderId("YOUR CUSTOMER ID");
$sms->number="1254578" // Number to send SMS 
$sms->type=1 // Promotional, transcational etc
$sms->send(); // Send SMS
```

Please check with their documentation for more details

http://www.infobip.com/messaging/app_developers/